# how to display number in a certain format in php

Tags: php

I'd like to display a number, integer or float in a uniform way like this:

if it is integer, for example 10, it should be displayed as 10.00
if it is a float already, for example 10.1, it should be displayed as 10.10
and if the float look like this 10.116, just display the first two number after the dot
regardless the left digits following the third one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$formatted = sprintf("%.2f", $your_number);
```

Alternatively, if you just want to print it out, and don't need it in a variable:

```
printf("%.2f", $your_number);
```

Answer (score 7):

refer [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
$x=number_format(10, 2);
```

Comment: not my downvote, but I don't think a lot of learning will occur by substituting two numbers :).

Answer (score 2):

check [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
echo number_format(10, 2); // will output 10.00
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use php's in built number_format() function. You can get more information from [php.net](http://my.php.net/number_format).