# How to add .00 in any value using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to add .00 to my value.

For example:

> 100 will be 100.00
>   100.26 will be 100.26 only.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to display number in a certain format in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402835/how-to-display-number-in-a-certain-format-in-php)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$YOUR_VALUE = 1000.25;
echo number_format($YOUR_VALUE, 2);
```

Comment: how do it with 100 to 100.00?

Answer (score 10):

[number_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) can be your friend

Answer (score 7):

Like @Gaurav said, use the `number_format()` function.  Simply pass it the value and the number of digits you want there to be after the decimal point:

```
$value = 100;
echo number_format($value, 2); //prints "100.00"
```

Note that by default, it will also insert commas as the thousands separator:

```
$value = 2013;
echo number_format($value, 2); //prints "2,013.00"
```

You can change the characters that are used as the decimal point and thousands separator by passing them in as the third and fourth parameters to the function:

```
$value = 2013;
echo number_format($value, 2, ',', ' '); //prints "2 013,00"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
number_format(100, 2, '.', ' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

[round](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)()

or

[number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)()