# Format of result from Round

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display number in a certain format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402835/how-to-display-number-in-a-certain-format-in-php)

```
echo round(10.1232, 2); // return 10.12
```

this working ok, but:

```
echo round(10, 2); // return 10
```

i would like receive **10.00**. How can i make it?

Comment: `10` (as a float) and `10.00` (as a float) are the same number *rendered* as different *string representations*; trailing zeros in the fraction are of no consequence to the *value* of a number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
echo number_format(10, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP also has `printf`:

```
printf( "%.2f\n", round(10.1232, 2) );
printf( "%.2f\n", round(10, 2) );
```

In fact, the rounding is handled by `printf` anyway...  So this should be the same:

```
printf( "%.2f\n", 10.1232 );
printf( "%.2f\n", 10 );
```

Comment: If you use printf, you wouldn't need to also use round. Just `printf('%.2f', 10.1232);` is fine.