# Split the long digit into small in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to display number in a certain format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5402835/how-to-display-number-in-a-certain-format-in-php)

I have following digit : `3234.54554545545`

```
I want to split it like 3234.54, means I want to display only 2 char after dot.

Following is something I am trying but its not working

<?php
$v = "3234.54554545";
$pos = strpos($v, '.');
$r = substr($v, count($pos) - 3);
echo $v."".$r;
?>
```

Actual result: `3234.54554545545`
Desired output : `3234.54`

Please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) function as:

```
$v = "3234.54554545";
$r = number_format($v, 2, '.', '');
```

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)?

```
<?php
    $v = "3234.54554545";
    $r = number_format($v, 2);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP is super-flexible with it's types, and numeric strings can be used directly as numbers.

```
//This is true
('123.45' == 123.45)
```

As such you can use [`number_format`](http://php.net/number_format) to format the string. You can also use [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf) if you need more control.